# Handling multiple jquery sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Im trying to make multiple jquery sliders that dynamically create a span with the value, but I am getting an instance of the value for each slider.

take a look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/houareau/RvSgj/182/

or

```
var a = 0;
$(".slider").each(function() {
var slider = this;
$(slider).slider({
    value : 5,
    min   : 1,
    max   : $(this).data('max'),
    step  : 1,
    slide : function (event, ui) {
       a = ui.value;
       $(slider).next().find('span.sliderValue').html(ui.value);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: I just want one instance of the span per slider.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to post the `create` function, which is the real issue here, you're appending both spans to both sliders.

```
$(".slider").each(function () {
    $(this).slider({
        min: 0,
        max: $(this).data('max'),
        step: 1,
        create: function (event, ui) {
            $(event.target).find('a').append($(event.target).next('.sliderValue'));
        },
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $(ui.handle).find('span.sliderValue').html(ui.value);
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RvSgj/189/)

And do **not** use a global variable to get the values, you can get a sliders value at any time by calling `$( ".selector" ).slider( "value" );`

Comment: Oh nice, thankyou! So if I wanted to generate the spans automatically? Like so... http://jsfiddle.net/houareau/RvSgj/184/

Comment: Do you know why Its not getting the max-data value from the div?
http://jsfiddle.net/houareau/RvSgj/188/

Comment: Ooops, you'd still need the loop for that, otherwise `this` is not the element

Answer (score 0):

Yay, here is the new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/houareau/RvSgj/186/)!

```
$(".slider").slider({
min: 0,
max: $(this).data('max'),
step: 1,
    create: function (event, ui) {           
        $(event.target).find('a').append( $('<span />').addClass('sliderValue') )
    },
slide: function (event, ui) {
    $(ui.handle).find('span.sliderValue').html(ui.value);
}
```

});